# Wagtail: Hook for changed order of subpages

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is there any way to hook into when changes are made to the ordering of subpages in the Wagtail admin?

We would like to bust our caching for our menu component, but would like to keep the cacheclearing to a minimum preferably by hooking into when the change of ordering is made by posting to the set position endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of Wagtail 2.6.1, I don't believe there is a way to hook into re-ordering pages. You can find all the available hooks in [the Wagtail hooks docs](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html).

Although you could propose this as a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_page_move` signal, [distinguish between a move and a reorder](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/signals.html#distinguishing-between-a-move-and-a-reorder), the retrieve the page index according to the children position (just like [Wagtail's `set_page_position`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/e30c25c3b1b5064ad95fbb68922baf0c14f0e252/wagtail/admin/views/pages/ordering.py#L23)):

```py
from wagtail.signals import post_page_move

def clear_page_url_from_cache_on_move(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['url_path_before'] == kwargs['url_path_after']:
        page = kwargs['instance']
        order = list(kwargs['parent_page_after'].get_children()).index(page)
        print('moved page %s - new order: %d' % (page.title, order))

post_page_move.connect(clear_page_url_from_cache_on_move)
```